# Why do class functions in React Components not have access to props?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I was running into a big problem where there was a function that did not have access to the props of the component in react:

```
renderRow(employee) {
    console.log('props here', this.props); //undefined
}
```

But when I changed it to a fat arrow function it works fine

```
renderRow = (employee) => {
   console.log('props here', this.props); //success?
}
```

Why is this? What am I not understanding?

Comment: you need to add `renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this)` inside your component constructor.

Comment: Looks like `renderRow` is called from a different context. The implicit variable `this` always refers to the current context in which the function executes. To make sure you point to the correct this one needs to either use `arrow` function that binds the method to the instance of the class or use `.bind` at the appropriate place binding it with correct `this`.

Comment: This must be a method you are using as an event handler. If so, you're putting the method out of context. Vanilla JSs `addEventListener` and its problem with context works the same way.

Comment: `this` inside your function and `this` inside arrow function has different scope, i suggest you to use arrow function whenever possible

Comment: Traditionally, the value of `this` primarily depends on who's calling the function. Here is one of the better explanations of `this` keyword in JS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work/3127440#3127440

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of the discussion. Let's say that your first function is a **normal function** and your second function is an **arrow function**

First of all, let's understand that for each **normal function execution** in JS, the JS engine creates it's own execution context. A new "this" is then created for each these execution context and thus belong to that function.

Now as it relates to your case, the **this** keyword on your first function

```
renderRow(employee) {
    console.log('props here', this.props); //undefined
}
```

refers itself (or to the function where it's currently being called), because the JS engine has created a new **this** object that refers to it. Thus when your program runs, this.props will have the value of undefined because it wasn't defined on the current execution context (which again, is your renderRow function)

On the other hand... the JS engine doesn't create a new **this** for **arrow functions**. To put it simply, an arrow function doesn't have it's own **this** and thus on your second example,

```
renderRow = (employee) => {
   console.log('props here', this.props); //success!!!
}
```

**this** refers to the outer execution context (which is your React Component) and so now this.props work.

For more information about the topics, you can check on these resources...

**THIS** - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

**ARROW FUNCTIONS** - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, `this` has another scope.

`employee` is the scope in your second example, which is why `this` references to `employee` there

Answer (score 0):

The fat arrow function works because `this` in arrow function doesn't rebind which helps keep it context and doesn't change on run time.

While `this`  in vanilla always refer to the outer scope, to use `this` on vanilla function you have to bind it to the employee function using the .bind() method

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions make our code more concise, and simplify function scoping and the this keyword.

Example:

```
    // ES5
    API.prototype.get = function(resource) {


   var self = this;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        http.get(self.uri + resource, function(data) {
            resolve(data);
          });
    });
};

// ES6
API.prototype.get = function(resource) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        http.get(this.uri + resource, function(data) {
            resolve(data);
         });
       });
};
```

for more detail check [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/)